# How to set page's title from the model in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my view code.

```
@model IEnumerable<TestApplication.Models.ApplicationUser>

@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = //what goes here? Model.FirstName?
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
             <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to change the ViewBag's title to whatever the FirstName is in the model. I am expecting something like `ViewBag.Title = Model.FirstName`. However doing so, I got an error. So what's the syntax?

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: You model is `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` has no properties. But why are you trying to assign  one of the `ApplicationUser` `FirstName` values to the `<title>` tag of the `<head>`?

Comment: I was just testing. It was a random thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your Model is of type `IEnumerable<TestApplication.Models.ApplicationUser>` so you cannot call a Property of the `ApplicationUser`

To demonstrate the problem, try this:

```
ViewBag.Title = Model.First().FirstName;
```

The error should disapear, but this is not the correct solution. You should consider *which* first name out of the list of users you want to display

Comment: same answer I will delete mine :)

Comment: I prefer using `Model.Select(x => x.FirstName).FirstOrDefault()` to `Model.First().FirstName`, since it directly return the string value and guarantees no exception will thrown if the result is null or empty.